# when i add apache deryby dependecy it gives error

Tags: java, spring-boot

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
    <artifactId>derby</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

when i add these it gives error like

```
Failure to transfer org.apache.derby:derby:jar:10.14.2.0 from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be
```

reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.derby:derby:jar:10.14.2.0 from/
to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): repo.maven.apache.org org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactTransferException: Failure to transfer
org.apache.derby:derby:jar:10.14.2.0 from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the
update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.derby:derby:jar:10.14.2.0 from/to central (https://
repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): repo.maven.apache.org at
org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultUpdateCheckManager.newException(DefaultUpdateCheckManager.java:240) at
org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultUpdateCheckManager.checkArtifact(DefaultUpdateCheckManager.java:208) at
org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.gatherDownloads(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:563) at
org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.performDownloads(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:481) at
org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:399) at
org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:224) at
org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveDependencies(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:338) at
org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.java:202) at
org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.resolveDependencies(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:212) at
org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:185) at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:
116) at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.readMavenProject(MavenImpl.java:628) at
org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.DefaultMavenDependencyResolver.resolveProjectDependencies(DefaultMavenDependencyResolver.java:63) at
org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager.refreshPhase2(ProjectRegistryManager.java:525) at
org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager.lambda$1(ProjectRegistryManager.java:489) at
org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:177) at
org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:151) at
org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager.refresh(ProjectRegistryManager.java:488) at
org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager.refresh(ProjectRegistryManager.java:349) at
org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager.refresh(ProjectRegistryManager.java:296) at
org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod.getProjectFacade(MavenBuilder.java:155) at
org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod$1.call(MavenBuilder.java:90) at
org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:177) at
org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:151) at
org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:99) at
org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod.execute(MavenBuilder.java:87) at
org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder.build(MavenBuilder.java:201) at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:833) at
org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45) at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:220) at
org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:263) at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$1.run(BuildManager.java:316) at
org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45) at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:319) at
org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuildLoop(BuildManager.java:371) at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:392) at
org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.doBuild(AutoBuildJob.java:154) at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.run(AutoBuildJob.java:244) at
org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run

Comment: Try `mvn clean install -U` and see if that resolves your issue

Comment: Glad it helped @Ri